# Объединять сервер и приложение в одно решение?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, проектирование

Разрабатываю приложение на C# с сайтом и web api на asp.net.
Стоит ли объединять web и не web в одно решение или сделать два?

Одно решение используют для одной программы или еще для множества разнопрофильных (как сервер и клиент)?

[image: Схема работы]

Comment: А вы разрабатывать, собирать, тестировать и распространять каждую версию их вместе будете или по отдельности?

Comment: @tym32167 По идее, в месте. Web сервер делает основные функции, web api и просто сайт, а приложение, как приятное дополнение, выполняющее роль "браузера".

Comment: Подумайте еще раз, у меня есть сомнения, что вам захочется на каждое даже незначительное изменение одной из частей вашей системы релизить всю систему целиком

Comment: Добавил схему работы программы.
Релизить систему целеком - это не проблемма.

Мои "колебания" мешающие выбрать заключаются в наличии общей библиотеке Server.ViewModels. Она отвечает за данные, которые предоставляет api. Сервер отправляет в json (или xml и т.п.), а приложение преобразует в ViewModel-класс и наоборот.

Comment: На мой взгляд других мыслей тут быть не может: это однозначно одно решение.

Comment: Смотрите, обычно, если вы пилите какое то небольшое конечное приложение, которое не предполагает дальнейшее усложнение и вы уверены, что над всем стеком, что Вы показываете, будет работать не больше одной команды - то по идее нет разницы, сколько вы сделаете решений. Если же ваше приложение будет только расти со временем, и планируется возможность, что над ui будет работать одна команда, над сервером другая, над мобильной версией третья, то тогда решения должны быть разные, репозитории разные, все разное.

Comment: Что касается общего кода, то вы всегда можете связать проекты через нугет или простой ссылкой на сборку.